# Асинхронный вызов метода WCF блокирует дальнейшие синхронные вызовы

Tags: c#, wcf, асинхронность, task, lock

Проблема полностью описана тут: [Async call to WCF client blocks subsequent synchronous calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818787/async-call-to-wcf-client-blocks-subsequent-synchronous-calls)

Принятых ответов, к сожалению, нет.

Один метод в контракте- асинхронный: `Task<CalcResult> CalcAsync();`

Второй - синхронный: `string GetData();`

На стороне клиента порядок вызовов такой:

```
var result = await _service.CalcAsync();
var data = _service.GetData();
```

На вызове _service.GetData() клиент зависает. Зависание происходит внутри метода GetData, причем метод отрабатывает нормально, но вот управление назад не приходит. Вероятно проблема с контекстом.

Вопросов. собственно говоря, несколько)

```
1) Почему может происходить такое зависание?

2) Можно ли в рамках одного контракта миксовать синхронные и
асинхронные методы?
```

P.S. Если сделать GetData асинхронным, то все работает штатно, проблема именно при переходе.

Обнаружил интересную деталь. Такое поведение наблюдается только тогда, когда к сервису подключено консольное приложение. В случае windows приложения (гуя) - все в порядке. Возможно как-то связано с переключением контекста. Получается при наличии потока диспетчера такой проблемы нет.

Comment: А какая у вас версия .Net Framework'а?

Comment: Версия фреймворка 4.6

Comment: var result = await _service.CalcAsync(); Идет асинхронный запрос и выполняется сл. инструкция var data = _service.GetData(); которая пытается выполнить запрос, но видимо сервер заблокирован, а await _service.CalcAsync(); не может завершить выполнение так как поток заблокирован _service.GetData(). В итоге deadlock.

Comment: тут или дожидаться явным образом await _service.CalcAsync() (что делает бессмысленным асинхронное выполнение) или _service.GetData() тоже делать асинхронным. Советую почитать А. Дэвис Асинхронное программирование в C# 5.0

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Так ведь дело в том, что в await осуществляется ожидание, _service.GetData() выполняется ведь только после того, как вернется результат задачи, разве не так?

Comment: Собственно, вы сами уже нашли причину: `SynchronizationContext` - его нет в консольном приложении. Я в своё время что-то читал на эту тему, разбирался, но, к стыду своему, уже всё позабыл... и сходу не могу внятно объяснить. Можно почитать Тауба: [1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/01/20/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/), [2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/01/21/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps-part-2/), [3](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/02/02/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps-part-3/).

Comment: Можно создать [кастомный](https://veganhunter.net/2016/12/02/synchronizationcontext-in-console-applications/) контекст.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!  Я подозревал, что дело в контексте, но нужен был взгляд со стороны) ну и за кастомный контекст отдельный плюс. Можете ли Вы оформить коммент в виде ответа, я его приму.

Comment: У меня данное поведение не воспроизводится, всё отрабатывает. Второй вызов, который синхронный, происходит в другом потоке, блокировки не происходит.

Comment: Зачем нужен в данном случае кастомный контекст? И какая именно тут проблема с контекстом?

Comment: А вы воспроизводили в консольном приложении? Такое поведение замечено только в рамках вызова сервиса из консольного приложения, в windows приложении все в порядке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Столкнулся с подобной проблемой, действительно, если вернуться к предыдущему контексту проблема исчезает. Сделать это можно через [Task.Yield](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.yield?view=net-5.0)

```
var result = await _service.CalcAsync();
await Task.Yield(); // <<<---
var data = _service.GetData();
```